# EXTJS - Can a Java Server make a call to the Browser Front end?

Tags: java, javascript, extjs, db2, extjs4.2

I have an EXTJS application that connects to a Java server.  The Java server calls a JDBC DAO that reads/writes to DB2 SQL Tables.  The front end is basically a simple grid.  Editing the grid makes an AJAX call to the server through a given URL, the URL is then handled by the Java which calls the JDBC DAO, updating the table, and the front end grid is refreshed after the change has taken place.

This is all pretty straightforward implementation.

However, now I need to be able to set up a listener on the EXTJS side which will refresh the grid's store when an external program changes the DB2 Database.  Essentially, whenever the SQL table updates, the front end should know and just do a store.load() to refresh the data.

However, I can't seem to find any information on how this possible.  It can be in the simplest possible way, even just sending a single (a 1 or 0 or a true or a false or something) that indicates to the front end that it needs to refresh.  Is this doable without a tremendous amount of overhead?

I assume I'll have to set up a Java database listener or something as well, so that the Java knows when the DB2 gets updated, then it can somehow alert the front end.

Can someone just give me a general heading?  As you can probably tell I'm not exactly fluent in this stuff, I'm relatively new to it all.

Edit: The Java server side stuff is hosted on a Tomcat server.

Comment: You can use websockets to send server side events to the client and avoid the chattiness of constant polling.  https://www.websocket.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this is the way: run a task which will update the grid in some time interval so that there is no need to handle at java side.

```
 var updateGrid=function(){
      grid.store.load();
 }
 var task = Ext.TaskManager.start({
    run: updateGrid,
      interval: 1000
  });
```

Comment: I actually like this idea and its probably what I'll go with but my worry is that if this tool becomes widely used the constant updating will put too much load on the server.  I really would like a way to only update when an actual change has occurred, to not bog down the server.

Comment: but still some listener should run continuously in the front end in your case